# What are some techniques to push changes from tokyo cabinet in a multi-service setup?

Tags: message-queue, soa, notifications, publish-subscribe, tokyo-cabinet

Let's say I have N > 1 TCP-based, connection-oriented (read: *not* a website) services handling connections from end users in some load-balanced/sharing configuration.

These users do things that cause updates to one or more keys in the centralized Tokyo Tyrant datastore.

What do you recommend to *push* these changes to interested users connected to a different service instance running on the same private network (same colo.)?

```
User 1     Service 1      Tokyo Tyrant      Service 2           User 2
------     ---------      ------------      ---------           ------
  |            |               |                |                 |
  ------> do something         |                |                 |
  |            |       ---> put K 42            |                 |
  |            |               |     ----> Hey! K is now 42       |
  |            |               |                |          ---> K was updated
```

A few ideas:

Broadcast the changes on successful update of the datastore from Service N to all other services

```
User 1     Service 1      Tokyo Tyrant      LAN Broadcast       Service 2       User 2
------     ---------      ------------      -------------       ---------       ------
  |            |               |                |                 |                |
  ------> do something         |                |                 |                |
  |            |       ---> put K 42            |                 |                |
  |            |       -----------------> Hey! K is now 42        |                |
  |            |               |                |         --> Hey! K is now 42     |
  |            |               |                |                 |         ---> K was updated
```

Store which Service each interested user is logged onto and send those services a message which is then relayed to the interested user; I suppose this is how IRC server-server connections work (need to research that).

```
User 1     Service 1      Tokyo Tyrant      Service 2           User 2
------     ---------      ------------      ---------           ------
  |            |               |                |                 |
  ------> do something         |                |                 |
  |            |       ---> put K 42            |                 |
  |            |       ---> who cares?          |                 |
  |            | <--- User 2 on Service 2       |                 |
  --------------------------------------> Hey! K is now 42        |
  |            |               |                |          ---> K was updated
```

Run a message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ); have each Service X subscribe to a queue on behalf of the interested users; post to it upon successful "put"s

```
User 1     Service 1      Tokyo Tyrant      RabbitMQ           Service 2    User 2
------     ---------      ------------      --------           ---------    ------
  |            |               |                | <--- subscribe --|         |
  ------> do something         |                |                  |         |
  |            |       ---> put K 42            |                  |         |
  |            | ------------------- post msg -->                  |         |
  |            |               |                |----- notify ---->|         |
  |            |               |                |                  |  ---> K was updated
```

Yet another idea is to pretend to be a replication slave and connect to the master.

In general, I'm looking for a way to get "change notifications" as found in CouchDB but for Tokyo Tyrant.  The idea is more general however.

If you suggest just using a message broker with persistent queues *instead* of a datastore like Tokyo Tyrant, please explain how I might hook into such to allow for validations, etc.  I am not intimate yet with such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation (and what I use) is the message broker approach. RabbitMQ keeps track on services (un)subscribing to different queues and you can use fanout exchanges.

Also, Tokyo Cabinet has a log (in a weird format though) which you can use to get the updates and push them to a queue. I only tried using a cron but I think it can be possible to get it in real time using a socket.